# How can I make rounded only one edge of the rectangle?

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

I have the following code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
       <stroke android:color="@color/conversation_border" android:width="1dp"/>
       <solid android:color="@color/conversation_is_user_bg"/>
            <corners android:radius="1dp" />
            <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="7dp"/>  
</shape>
```

When i apply it to TextView, all is OK.
but when i replace

```
<corners android:radius="1dp" />
```

with

```
<corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
          android:topLeftRadius="0"
          android:topRightRadius="0"
          android:bottomRightRadius="0" />
```

I have anexception. 
I already tried not to remove `android:radius` attribute, provide radius in px and dp, and result is always

```
error!
UnsupportedOperationException: null
```

which is very descriptive.
What am I doing wrong and how to round only bottom left corner of the text view?

Comment: That is a bug in android ,this code will work perfectly in android devices running on version 2.2 or above .

Comment: android 2.3.3 in emulator, r2

Comment: i was having the same problem in android 1.6 device but worked perfectly in 2.2

Comment: hmm... i'll try it with other versions and post you back if it is working or not

Comment: It will not work in emulator. Try on device.

Comment: check this link http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9161

Comment: yes,that was a bug in android. i misspelled version of emulator, I has r1, not r2 here. And after upgrade to r2 it works fine, yet with inverted corners as in your link, but at least it shows corners. Thank you!

Comment: there is a similar question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003382/how-can-i-work-around-android-issue-9161-where-bottomrightradius-and-bottomleftr

Comment: the worst disappointment in google i has was it's buggy development environment... :( After visual studio it is awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug in android emulator, thanks to all who answered.
After updating emulator to latest version all is working without modifications (exept [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9161) , but there is walkaround for it)

Answer (score 1):

Just leave one option:

```
<corners 
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
/>
```

Comment: So it must be something else than shape. Could you paste stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

try this one...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/corners_blue_random">
    <solid android:color="@color/conversation_is_user_bg" />
    <corners android:radius="1dip" android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="1dip" android:bottomRightRadius="1dip"
        android:topRightRadius="1dip" />
    <stroke android:color="@color/conversation_border"
        android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="1dip" android:bottomRightRadius="1dip"
        android:topRightRadius="1dip" />

</shape>
```