# How to set corner radiuses for the button in java code?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to set the rounded corners without xml. How can I do it in java code?

```
Button b = new Button (this);
b.set???? (??) ;
```

I tried to write b.setCornerRadius(3.0f), but it is undefined for button object.
Thanks.

Comment: have a look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003382/how-can-i-work-around-android-issue-9161-where-bottomrightradius-and-bottomleft

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a shape in your drawable folder and set the desired radius and set this drawable as background to your button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Hi Gabi, thanks for the answer. I created the xml file as you wrote, but how can I receive reference to rectangle in the code? I suppose it is something like b.setBackground(getResources().????). What I write instead of ??

Comment: you just need to get the drawable (drawable being the name of this xml) and set is as background to your button (if you do this from code) or just the background in xml the name of your xml

Comment: If the xml is named "some_drawable.xml", you can do it via the following: `b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.some_drawable);`

Answer (score 31):

Use GradientDrawable

```
GradientDrawable gdDefault = new GradientDrawable();
gdDefault.setColor(bgColor);
gdDefault.setCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
gdDefault.setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor);
```

Comment: how to assign the 'gdDefault' to the button?

Comment: anyView.setBackGroundDrawable(gdDefault);

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

Comment: Hi Clemp6r, I saw now the link, but I still don't understand what should I write exactly. If you can to write some example or some explanation please. Thanks.

Comment: The example of @gabi is right. Create an XML file like his example, and apply the resulting drawable in java using button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.the_drawable_name).

Answer (score 0):

Try setGradientRadius(). setCornerRadius() set wrong size.

```
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)image.getBackground();
drawable.setGradientRadius(radiuspx);
```