# Setting the button radius programmatically in android

Tags: android, button, cornerradius

I have a button say `myButton`. I want to set the top left corner radius of the button programmatically. 
      I'm looking for something like

```
myButton.setTopLeftCornerRadius(10);
```

I have looked for a method like 'setcornerradius' in eclipse but got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shape drawable for this or rounded corner background Image.
For shape drawable detail please see this post.

[How to set corner radiuses for the button in java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709595/how-to-set-corner-radiuses-for-the-button-in-java-code)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Button is type of `View` and all `View`s in Android occupy rectangular areas. However, you can set the background of the button to any image you like. Like a [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) with round corners.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for draw the rounded corners edittext:

[How to create EditText with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners)