# Corner Radius and item drawable in code

Tags: android, drawable

I have this xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/back" />
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid/>
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#25786" />
            <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
            <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" 
                     android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

Now i am doing it via code:

```
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];

    ShapeDrawable sd1 = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    sd1.getPaint().setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    sd1.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    sd1.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(1);

    layers[0] = sd1;

    LayerDrawable composite = new LayerDrawable(layers);
```

But i am not able to code it for `<corners android:radius="10dip"/>` and `<item android:drawable="@drawable/back" />`

How to do it?

**EDIT 1**

```
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];

ShapeDrawable sd1 = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
sd1.getPaint().setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
sd1.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);
sd1.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(1);
sd1.getPaint().setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(10));

layers[1] = sd1;
layers[0] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pie_chart_back);

LayerDrawable composite = new LayerDrawable(layers);
```

Comment: To set corners from code see (Gradient Drawables): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709595/how-to-set-corner-radiuses-for-the-button-in-java-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like in your XML, you'll need three `Drawable`s, not one. One is a [`LayerDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) containing the others. The other one missing could be a [`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) depending on `@drawable/back`.

The corner effect you're looking for is in the [`CornerPathEffect`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/CornerPathEffect.html) of your `Drawable`'s `Paint`, see [`Paint.setPathEffect`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setPathEffect%28android.graphics.PathEffect%29).

Comment: @Goofy You're right, the `LayerDrawable` is already there, so only the `BitmapDrawable` is missing. -- What do you mean by "the CornerPathEffect _is not there_?

Comment: I am sorry i didnt not see it properly, can you please chek my edit and let me know is it fine now?

Comment: @Goofy Your SDK and AVD can tell you much better than I can whether or not it's now working. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this...!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#e1e1e1" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#808080" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />

</shape>
```