# Android: Button - Swapped rounded Corners APIs 8 till 12 - How to fix it?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-view, android-xml, android-button

I know that this is a known bug, so I've tried following solution:
[How can I work around Android issue 9161, where bottomRightRadius and bottomLeftRadius are swapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003382/how-can-i-work-around-android-issue-9161-where-bottomrightradius-and-bottomleft)
(See answer Joss Stuart)
My drawables folder structure:
- drawable-hdpi (here I planted the xml-file with the swapped values)
- drawable-ldpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-v12 (here I planted the xml-file with the correct values)
- drawable-xdpi
On Android API 8 - 12 the button's rounded corners are shown correctly, but are swapped on API 17.
It seems that my Android API 17 is not getting the xml-file values from the drawable-v12 folder.
Does anybody know why and how to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: instead of fighting with that, why not to use nine patch drawables?

Comment: `It seems that my Android API 17 is not getting the xml-file values from the drawable-v12 folder.`... and why should an API **17** device take values from the **drawable-v12** folder?! It should take values from the **drawable-v17** folder, instead. Does it make sense?

Comment: @ Bob Malooga: Nope. According to the solution link above that I provided, all APIs 12 and above should take the values from the drawable-v12 folder. See for more info this link:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9161#c6

Comment: @ pskink: Yup, thanks for reminding me :)  I'll try that if I get no specific solution here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by adding a "drawable"-folder in res/ and by moving the xml-file with the swapped values in drawable-hdpi to the "drawable"-folder.
So at the end your folder structure should look like this:
- drawable (xml-file with swapped values)
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-ldpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-v12 (xml-file with the correct values)
- drawable-xdpi

Comment: Ohoowo... ...a downvote for a correct answer without a comment :) A possibility that somebody here is angry with me and this somebody forgot to think logically, because he was overrun by a feeling (his anger about that other people are so stupid but in fact it is him, who did not get the information right). If that somebody is not you, please comment your downvote. Thank you.